# Importing module in same folder not working

Tags: python, import

I was trying to `import` a py file in one of the files.
The folder is `A`, and `B` and `C` are files inside that.
I want to get `C` in `B`. I tried `import C` and `from . import C`. None of those worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't import a PY file, you import elements defined in that file.  Can you be more clear about your file organization, and what you are trying to import?  And finally, what error messages are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't matter that `C` and `B` are in the same folder. What is relevant is what the current working directory (CWD) is when `B` is executing. How are you running `B`? Also see [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: @JohnLadasky Hi, Thanks for your response. I figures it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "You don't import a PY file, you import elements defined in that file." - That might be the more common case, but it's also perfectly normal to import an entire module.  It's done all the time, including with the most popular packages in the python ecosytem.